# How do I pass stateful array from child to parent component? React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this CreateArea component in which I gather data inputted from the user and set its state locally in notes array with setNote.

What I want to do is be able to then display below the CreateArea component as many Note components as there are items in my notes array.

But my confusion is that I have this stateful array within the CreateArea component, but I need access to it within the parent App component so that I can render these Note components.

How do I create as many Note components as are in my array aka how do I get access to that array within the parent App component?

```
import React from "react";

function CreateArea() {
  const [notes, setNote] = React.useState([
    {
      title: "",
      content: ""
    }
  ]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setNote({
      ...notes,
      [event.target.name]: value
    });
    console.log(notes);
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(notes);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          value={notes.title}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="title"
          placeholder="Title"
        />
        <textarea
          value={notes.content}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="content"
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          rows="3"
        />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateArea;
```

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea />
      <Note 
        title="title"
        content="content"
      />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

There are likely quite a few ways to get the result you're looking for. The first one that came to mind for me was using a callback. (This may be misguided since some context for how other elements are rendering aren't represented). The example is rough but I hope it provides some value:

```
function CreateArea(callback) {

  function handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    callback({
      ...notes,
      [event.target.name]: value
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          value={notes.title}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="title"
          placeholder="Title"
        />
        <textarea
          value={notes.content}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="content"
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          rows="3"
        />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [notes, setNote] = React.useState({});

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea callback={setNote} />
      <div>
        {notes.map(note => <Note
          title="title"
          content={note}
        />)}
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```